# Java EE how to break chain in filter and return the response

Tags: java-ee-8

How to break chain filter in java ee and return response? I don't want to execute my rest endpoint if security validation fails. For now my code just return from the function but I need send to user information what is goin on.

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest requ = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        if(!valid){
           return;
        }
        
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle this is to use `sendRedirect`.

Instead of

```
        if(!valid){
           return;
        }
```

You can have the following to display custom messages on the page e.g. mypage.action:

```
        if(!valid){
            log("Unauthorized access request");
            response.sendRedirect("mypage.action");
        } else {
           chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?